# array from post into a single mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that is built based on dynamic rows that changes every time. I am able to post the array but i get each field in a separate row. How can i insert the array into a single row.
Here is my PHP:

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['item_name'])) {
        $table = $_POST['ItemTypeSelect'];
        $array = array();
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $variable) {
            $chesckColumn = mysql_query("SELECT `$key` from $table");
            if (!$chesckColumn) {
                echo "column ".$key." does not exist <br/>";
            }else{
                $results = $variable;
                $columnName = $key;
                $array[$columnName] = $results;
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (`$columnName`) VALUES ('$results') ")or die(mysql_error());

            }
        }
                print_r($array);
        }


?>
```

The print array is :

```
Array
(
    [Server_id] => 
    [Server_IP_Address] => 123456789
    [Server_IP2] => 123456789
    [Server_Name] => Server
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table = $_POST['ItemTypeSelect'];
$isert_vals = "VALUES(";
$insert_table = "INSERT INTO `".$table."` (";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $variable) {
    $chesckColumn = mysql_query("SELECT `$key` from $table");
    if (!$chesckColumn) {
        echo "column ".$key." does not exist <br/>";
    } else {
        $results = $variable;
        $columnName = $key;
        $array[$columnName] = $results;
        $insert_table.="`".$columnName."`,";
        $isert_vals.="'".$results."',";
    }
}    
$isert_vals   = substr($isert_vals , 0 ,-1).") ";    
$insert_table = substr($insert_table , 0 ,-1).") ";

$query = $insert_table.$isert_vals;
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
if (isset($_POST['item_name'])) {
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ItemTypeSelect']);
    $array = array();
    $cols = array();
    $vals = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $variable) {
        $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
        $variable = mysql_real_escape_string($variable);
        $chesckColumn = mysql_query("SELECT `$key` from $table");
        if (!$chesckColumn) {
            echo "column ".$key." does not exist <br/>";
        } else {
            $cols[] = $key;
            $vals[] = $variable;
        }
    }

    $columns = implode(",", $cols);
    $values = implode("," , $vals);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values)") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Be aware that mysql extension is deprecated. Consider using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).
And note that you should always sanitize your database input to prevent sql-injections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build one INSERT statement, rather than executing a new one each time you go through your loop.

Also, please note that the mysql_* functions are **deprecated** - you should use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Finally, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements, or all sorts of Very Bad Things will happen to your database, app, server, toaster, and dog.

Comment: Thanks Ed, i was able to solve it thanks to @Farkhad. every one is telling me to stay away from mysql and learn MySQLi - i just started learning mysql and not sure where to beign to shift my focus on MySQLi.

Comment: The manual at php.net has lots of good info on MySQLi. The good news is that most of the functions and logic are similar to the mysql_* functions, but much more flexible (like good OOP support) and much more secure, if you use them correctly.